# LaTeX code in legend table in Qti-Plot

Tags: plot, external-files, tools

I want to use LaTeX code in the legend table of a plot in the [qti-plot](https://www.qtiplot.com/) software. Does anyone know how one could e.g. write `$4\cdot 10^{-5}$`?

Answer (score 1):

The procedure is as follows:

1. make a graph in QtiPlot
2. double click on the graph area to go to `Plot details` and select `Legend`
3. enable the checkbox that says `TeX Output`
4. type the LaTeX code in the box below

   - note that you need to type also the math mode delimiter `$`
   - to keep the legend bar you need to start the line with `\l(n)` with *n* the number of the legend item starting with 1

The dialog should look like the screenshot below:
[image]

5. click <kbd>Apply</kbd> and then <kbd>OK</kbd>

The raw LaTeX code is now shown in the graph:
[image]

6. select `Export Graph` from the `File` menu
7. select `*.tex` as format and choose a filename and path
8. click <kbd>Ok</kbd>. Now a file `yourname.tex` is created with the graph. This file can be added to your own LaTeX document using `\input`. It uses the TikZ package, so you need `\usepackage{tikz}` in the preamble of your document. An example document that can be used to compile the graph is as follows (this example assumes that the exported file is called `qtigraph.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\input{qtigraph}
\end{document}
```

Now, the graph is compiled with the legend contents rendered by LaTeX (note that I used the trial version of QtiPlot which leaves a watermark - I presume this is not visible in the full version):

[image]

Note that if you want only the graph itself with rendered contents and not embed it in an existing document then you can use `\documentclass{standalone}` instead of `\documentclass{article}`.